# Laravel class not found even the class is there

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a weird issue with resolving my classes in a Laravel application.

```
use App\Enums\UserRoles;
use App\Enums\SocialMedia;
use App\Models\Action;


class SomeController extends Controller {



    protected function createUserFB(): Action {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        $this->extracted($user, SocialMedia::FACEBOOK); // <-- ERROR HERE !! 
    }


 }
```

The SocialMedia class is in Enums.php file

```
<?php
namespace App\Enums;

class SocialMedia {
    const FACEBOOK = "facebook";
    const GOOGLE = "google";
    const TWITTER = "twitter";
}
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
[2021-06-28 20:53:41] local.ERROR: Class "App\Enums\SocialMedia" not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class \"App\\Enums\\SocialMedia\" not found at ...
```

I have execute

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and restarted the server ...

Comment: Have you dumped the autoload? It's like the Laravel version of turning it off and on again, but it's not included in the question so I feel like its worth asking..

Comment: @BrianThompson if you mean this command composer dump-autoload then yes

Answer (score 3):

Kindly rename the file *Enums.php* to *SocialMedia.php*, then run
`composer dump-autoload`

This error is from autoloader trying to load the namespace for the class. Kindly check [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for the PHP Standard Recommendation for Autoloading.

Comment: But I need it called Enums.php because this is what it is ...

Comment: @Adelin This is the correct answer, The autoloading standards requires the class name to match the filename.